# What does "cite" mean under a question?

Tags: discussion, citation

On the Stack Exchange site [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/), I saw an additional option, "cite", next to the usual "edit, follow, flag and share" on a question there:

[image]

I have not seen this option on any other site, yet.  What is it for?

Comment: There are a number of other sites that have the "cite" button, so this is on-topic here.

Comment: I'll leave my comment so that others don't vote to close this.

Comment: @Ollie As Sonic stated, there are other sites, such as Math and Math Overflow, that also provide "cite". The closely related question [How to properly cite someone on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/326762/562482), and particular this [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/326763/562482), I believe will help to explain the purpose and use of the "cite" option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> What is it for?

To make it easier for people writing research publications or other types of documents to cite Stack Exchange questions or answers. The cite option generates a reference that is easy to cite in TeX, which is often used by researchers (and pretty much always in maths/physics/computer science). A few other SE websites have this option such as https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks.  John Omelian's comment, and this, answered my question - and raised another:  Why isn't this option shown everywhere on the network?

Comment: @Ollie I believe the rationale is only showing `cite` on SE websites are more likely to be cited in research publications. With that being said I'd prefer to have the cite option on all websites.

Comment: I would too, I'm already working on a feature request :D